# SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Opening and ending tag mismatch - open single quote

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
$data = $d->getpage_XML($url, $redirect=FALSE,$d);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

my Output:

```
<record>
<subfield> text '10</subfield>
<subfield2> text 2 </subfield2>
<subfield3> text 3 '16</subfield3>
</record>
```

the single quotes return me the error:

> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): parser error : Opening and ending tag
>   mismatch

How can I escape single quotes in Simple XML string?

Comment: It's not valid XML.  `&apos;`

Comment: Ok, but how can I handle it?

Comment: The single quote is not a problem see: https://3v4l.org/7WePJ So You might get a different response, debug `$data`.

Comment: Sorry what should I do in my case?

Comment: @newert Try to output the actual content of `$data`, and write a [mcve], since we can't run your `getpage_XML`, so can't know what it returns.

Comment: Can you give exampls please?

Comment: I just need a solution if the xml content has ' - single quote.

Comment: @newert The single quote is not the problem, as demonstrated on ThW's link, so you need to keep looking to find out what the problem is. We can't help you do that without you giving us more information, and a version of the code that let's us see the error for ourselves.

Comment: What information do you need? The single quote is problem because when I removed quotes from xml, it parsed very well.

Comment: @newert What we need is a [mcve] - some code that actually shows the error happening. The code you have pasted does not give any errors; we can't tell you how to fix errors that aren't there.

Comment: Hi, I tested your way, it is ok when I paste my full XML into: $data = <<<'XML' and XML; but when I obtain the XML with two single quotes direct from URL: $d = $dois->getpage_XML($url, $redirect=FALSE,$d); I obtain the error SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch

Comment: Also the issue Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML Stack trace: #0 SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<html>\n<head>\n<...') #1 {main} thrown on line 163: $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

Comment: @newert Take a closer look at that error message, the XML you're actually trying to parse begins `<html>\n<head>\n<...`, not `<record>...`. When debugging, make sure you're not viewing the output as HTML: use "View Source" or "Inspect Element" in the browser, or save the data to a file and open it in a text editor.